Olive tree suckers but no top growth at all
After 2 horrendous winters in UK my once bushy olive tree appeared to be dead. It was previously planted out in probably not the best location or soil conditions but I’ve now dug it up and replanted in a large tub, being careful to use a recommended mix of quality top soil, compost and perlite. After almost 9 months I’m now seeing suckers at the base of the trunk but nothing at all at the top - so should I just leave these and maybe end up with a “shrub” or cut them off to try and stimulate growth at the top? The bark is green underneath only for about c8 inches at the bottom and light brown thereafter. If I end up cutting off the majority of the trunk will this further distress the tree??


+1 I wonder if it's possible to encourage budding/branching of the alive part.

Removing dead parts of a tree or any plant won't cause distress to the plant, so yes you can cut down the dead trunk. If your olive tree was grafted though, the rootstock growth may not be the same olive variety as the upper part of the tree was, but this might not be important to you, since I don't imagine you were growing it as a cropping plant.

I can't spot signs of a graft union from that picture, though several from other angles might be  better to make that determination with any confidence.
